# Google spreadsheet script very slow

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a script that i run each day.  it's incredibly slow and i can't figure out what's slowing it down.  Anyone have any suggestions?  I originally wrote a function to do one sheet, then i added a function to loop and call it on every sheet.

```
function addAllLog() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  // build array of all sheets
  for (var i in allSheets) { 
    if (i == 0) { continue;}  // skip first sheet

    var tmpName = allSheets[i].getName();
    if (tmpName == "Print Sheet")  break;  //stop at this tab

    var tmpName = ss.getSheetByName(allSheets[i].getName());
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(allSheets[i].getName()));

    addLog();
  }
}

function addLog () {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var numLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var numThisRow = numLastRow+1;
    today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
    today = Utilities.formatDate(today,"EDT","MM/DD/YYYY");

    if (sheet.getMaxRows() == numLastRow) sheet.insertRowAfter(numLastRow);

    var range = sheet.getRange(numLastRow,2,1,16); // last row, column b, 1 row of 16 columns
    var data = range.getValues();

    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(numLastRow+1, 2,1,16)); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()

    sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 1).setValue(today);
    sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 4).setValue('Log');
    sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 5).setValue('');  //erase copied value if there was anything there
    sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 7).setValue('');  //erase copied value if there was anything there

    sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 6).setValue('=GoogleFinance(C' + numThisRow + ',"price")');
    sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 6).setValues(sheet.getRange(numThisRow,6).getValues());

}
```

Any suggestions on speeding it up would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Each time you set a value in a range directly over the Spreadsheet, it takes at least 800ms to do it, so the best way to face this problem is create an `Object[][]` with the values and set it with `sheet.getRange(range).setValues(Object[][])`, being sure that `Object[][]` has the same width-height of the `range`.

In this post, [Best Practices | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices), Google explains the difference.

Also, an interesting solution is make an [Spreadsheet abstraction in memory](https://dzone.com/articles/beating-the-apps-script-clock-say-hello-to-memshee). I make my own [MemsheetApp](https://github.com/celeiva815/MemsheetApp), based in this approach and it works very nice. I'm receiving pull request if you want to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This version doesn't require that you activate each sheet so it may take a little less time.

```
function addAllLog() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i=1;i<allSheets.length;i++){ 
    var shtname = allSheets[i].getName();
    if (shtname == "Print Sheet"){
      break;  //stop at this tab
    }else{
      addLog(shtname);
    }
  }
}

function addLog (shtname) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(shtname);
  var numLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numThisRow = numLastRow+1;
  today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate()-1);
  today = Utilities.formatDate(today,"EDT","MM/DD/YYYY");
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() == numLastRow) sheet.insertRowAfter(numLastRow);
  var range = sheet.getRange(numLastRow,2,1,16); 
  range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(numLastRow+1, 2,1,16)); 
  sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 1).setValue(today);
  sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 4).setValue('Log');
  sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 5).setValue('');
  sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 7).setValue('');
  sheet.getRange(numThisRow, 6).setFormula('=GoogleFinance(C' + numThisRow + ',"price")');
}
```

Comment: I tried to use an array, but there are formulas in many cells.  and when i did `var data = range.getValues();` it only gets the actual values so it didn't have the formulas in it.  i took out most of the `setValues` and that doesn't seem to effect the speed.  i moved the data stuff outside the function  so it's a global variable and it no effect (not thta i thought it would).  i just don't understand why it takes 30 seconds per sheet to copy the line and change a few cells.   b/c it takes so long i can't set this up as an automatic trigger.

Comment: I made a few small changes that might speed it up a bit.  Wouldn't you rather have the more recent value at the top of the file?

Comment: I made those changes, there was a line in there that did nothing that i needed to delete.   I had it with the newest data at the top but really didn't like it so went back.   It appears that slowest line is really the `range.copyTo` line.  There has to be another way around this, to copy formulas and data.

Comment: If you want to copy formulas and data copyTo is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be Google's fault. Even `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName()` is bottlenecking the script by a minute or so, in my tests.